# np.sum/np.count_nonzero() up to some maximum number

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization

When I want to compare the sum of an array to some number, I would write it like this.

```
if np.sum(some_array) > 10:
```

But for an array, where the condition of the sum being larger than 10 might be found after the first few entries:

```
some_array = np.array([5, 4, 3, 6, 9])
```

is there a way to not have to sum up the whole array and compare it to said number, for example something like this:

```
running_sum = 0
flag = False
for entry in my_array:
    running_sum += entry
    if running_sum > threshold:
        flag = True
        break
```

but directly in numpy without the python loop, which is normally considered slow when compared to numpy operations?

EDIT: I know about cumsum, but then it would be faster to just compute the whole sum a single time, because the actual index when the threshold is reached is not important for me.

Comment: That's like asking for a LEGO set that provides flexible sized blocks.

Comment: Your need seems too precise so that Numpy implements that. However, you can use Numba to do this quite efficiently.